# Conditional Bulk Update in SQL Server for multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am attempting to update a few hundred thousand rows, where two columns have a specific value ('xxx').

```
ID | firstname  | lastname
----------------
1  |  John      | xxx
2  |  xxx       | Scheving
3  |  Agnes     | xxx
4  |  Luke      | Borden
5  |  Kayla     | Borden
6  |  Finnick   | Wayne
7  |  xxx       | xxx
```

I need to do it in batches to not lock the table completely. Currently, my query looks like this

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;
DECLARE @rows INT, @count INT, @message VARCHAR(100);
SET @rows = 1;
SET @count = 0;

WHILE @rows > 0
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRAN
         UPDATE TOP (2000) people
         SET firstname= CASE firstname WHEN 'xxx' THEN 'N/A' ELSE firstname  END,
         lastname= CASE lastname WHEN 'xxx' THEN 'N/A' ELSE lastname END

        SET @rows = @@ROWCOUNT
        SET @count = @count + @rows
        RAISERROR('COUNT %d', 0, 1, @count) WITH NOWAIT
    COMMIT TRAN
END
```

But I worry about the performance of this query or if it can be easier to update those columns rather than using a case.

Comment: Add `WHERE firstname = 'xxx' or lastname = 'xxx'` to keep write-set size down.

Comment: Why do is that way? Why not use `WHERE`? Then you're not going to be updating thousands of rows. Provided that `firstname` and `lastname ` are indexed *well* then the number of rows you need to update will be far lower. The `CASE` expression isn't the problem, it's the lack of a `WHERE`.

Comment: BTW, I'd go with NULL instead of 'N/A' or 'xxx'.

Comment: And what will happen when an actual error is encountered? Your code just continues on and on and on and on ...  Batches of 2000 seem to be far too small. You worry - but why? You terminate some statements - but none inside your loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see value to updating both columns at the same time, so I would suggest something like this:

```
update people
    set firstname = 'N/A'
    where firstname = 'XXX';

update people
    set lastname = 'N/A'
    where lastname = 'xxx';
```

If you want to put these in loops, then you can just repeat:

```
declare @reccnt int;
set @reccent = 1;

while @reccnt > 0
begin
    update top (2000) people
        set firstname = 'N/A'
        where firstname = 'XXX';

    set @reccnt = @@ROWCOUNT;
end;
```

And for the last name as well.

Comment: Being new to SQL, somehow I thought that it would be more efficient updating both columns at the same time, rather than run through the table again. I think this answer makes the most sense.